# Android NDK UnsatisfiedLinkError: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

Since two days, I get this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load MyCPPProject from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.mypackage.myApp-3.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.mypackage.myApp-3]: findLibrary returned null
```

I'd like to compile a project c ++ natively in android application. 
The project compiles fine on another PC but not on mine. 
I tried to create a new workspace, install another eclipse and plenty others solutions but it still does not compile.

How can I fix it ? 
The android project generate myApp.apk but not myApp-3.apk.

```
[dexPath=/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.mypackage.myApp-3.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.mypackage.myApp-3]
```

Why compiler try to load myApp-3.apk ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by creating armeabi inside libs folder. And copied the .so files into armeabi folder.